# Angular ng-repeat error, can't get values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

0 votar contra favorita

I'm returning a Json with this code:

```
$scope.movies = angular.toJson(results, true);
```

and getting this json: http://pastebin.com/87tJm8XE

I try to return this data with:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="movie in movies">
    {{movie.title}}
</ion-item>
```

but I was getting this error:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys.
```

so I change to:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="movie in movies track by $index">
   {{movie.title}}
</ion-item>
```

But now I dont know how to get the values. {{movie.title}} return empty.

tks

Comment: Seeing as your error is simply using the wrong value, you might consider learning how to properly use a debugger or developer tools as this can be quite easily spotted using them.

Answer (score 4):

Functions:

```
angular.toJson( result ); // JSON -> String
angular.fromJson( result ); // String -> JSON
```

That said, the example would look like:

**file.js:**

```
var results = json.data.results; // Where the variable "json" is http://pastebin.com/87tJm8XE
$scope.movies = angular.fromJson(results);
```

Or:

```
$scope.movies = results;
```

**view.html:**

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="movie in movies">
    {{movie.title}}
</ion-item>
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Chofoteddy/J2LH6/

Comment: @PedroMarques Glad you has been helpful. To close the question as resolved, mark the answer with the checkmark next to the answer that has been useful to you.

Tutorial: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work